# What is the correct layout of Python code when using --symlink-install in ROS 2?

Tags: python, ros2, colcon, setup.py, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to write a Python node in ROS 2. Here is my package directory layout (assume `pkgname` is my ROS package's name):

```
pkgroot/
+-- scripts/
    +-- node.py
+-- src/
    +-- pkgname/
        +-- src.py
+-- setup.py
+-- setup.cfg
+-- package.xml
```

This directory is put under `workspace/src/`.

My `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
package_name = "pkgname"
setup(
    name=package_name,
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    scripts=["scripts/node.py"],
    zip_safe=True
)
```

`colcon build` works normally as usual. But when I'm trying to use the `--symlink-install` option, colcon tells me:

`error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'src' does not exist or is not a directory`

After inspecting the `build` directory, I found that colcon created a symlink to `workspace/src/pkgroot/pkgname` instead of `workspace/src/pkgroot/src/pkgname`.

Since I want to separate `scripts` and `src` directory, I don't want to put the actual Python module code (`pkgroot/src/pkgname`) directly under my package root (`pkgroot/pkgname`).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309103/what-is-the-correct-layout-of-python-code-when-using---symlink-install-in-ros-2?/) by [Mut Ze](https://answers.ros.org/users/38645/mut-ze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-11-22**:
There should be no need to change the package layout in order to work with `--symlink-install`. The option should work transparently. Since your layout is not the default for Python packages we might not have encountered that case yet hence the problem.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-11-22**:
Please share are ready-to-build package and I am happy to take a closer look why it fails and how `colcon-python-setup-py` needs to be patches to support this use case.

**Comment by [Mut Ze](https://answers.ros.org/users/38645/mut-ze/) on 2018-11-22**:
Hello, here is the link to the package source: https://github.com/mutongx/ros2-python-symlink-install-test

Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [ar13pit](https://answers.ros.org/users/37956/ar13pit/) on 2020-01-29**:
Hi @Dirk Thomas,

I stumbled upon a similar problem. Trying out a bare minimum ros2-python package provided by @Mut Ze in the link https://github.com/mutongx/ros2-python-symlink-install-test a new issue pops up.

Seems like the `scripts` option of `setup.py` is not supported by `colcon-core`. Will all the options available with `setup.py` be supported or are there restrictions to the supported options, as I'm unable to find any documentation in this regard.

Thanks,

Arpit

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-01-29**:
@ar13pit Please create a new question instead. Also I don't think the statement "the scripts option of setup.py is not supported by colcon-core" is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `setup.py` file of the package is using `package_dir` which older versions of `colcon`didn't support. Please update `colcon-core` to at least version 0.3.14. See https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/pull/137 for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-01-02**:
@Mut Ze please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

**Comment by [Mut Ze](https://answers.ros.org/users/38645/mut-ze/) on 2019-01-02**:
Oh thanks! Looks like that I missed the previous email... Sorry for the long delay and thanks again for your help.